# How to convert MYSQL query into MSSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, mssql-jdbc

I've 700+ MySQL queries and now trying to create same set of queries in MSSQL.

I want to generate MSSQL query with same MYSQL.Is any way to convert MYSQL query into MSSQL query.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no free tool that will do this for you. you can start here: http://www.convert-in.com/mssql-to-mysql-queries.htm

Answer (score 4):

From this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/12/06/converting-mysql-queries-to-ms-sql-server-queries.aspx) by [Brian Swan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/), you can download the [SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42657) and use it to convert a single MySQL query to a SQL Server query:

1. Create a Project: All the information you need for downloading SSMA, creating a project and connecting to databases is in steps 1-6 of [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/08/12/now-available-sql-server-migration-assistant-for-mysql.aspx).
2. In the MySQL Metadata Explorer, navigate to the Statements directory of your MySQL database:

[image]

3. Paste the query you want to convert into the query editor window, e.g:
   `SELECT post_title, post_date FROM wp_posts ORDER BY post_date LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5;`

[image]

4. Back in the MySQL metadata explorer, right-click Statements and select Convert Schema:

[image]

5. When prompted to save changes, select Yes:

[image]

6. Copy the converted query from the SQL Server query editor window:

[image]

Note that SSMA will not successfully translate all MySQL queries, but it does for most. It does not translate some MySQL-specific functions (for example `FOUND_ROW()`).

Comment: I'm using SQL Yog and there is no Statement option in that. Can you tell me how to do that with SQL Yog.

Comment: Yes I installed SSMA. I created statement and paste one create query in Sql Editor but convert schema option disabled when I right-clicked created statement. How can I enable  convert schema??

Comment: Did you actually follow the step-by-step installation instructions from this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/08/12/now-available-sql-server-migration-assistant-for-mysql.aspx)?

Comment: yes, I can create statement,save,create Report but convert schema option disabled.